# use custom font in devexpress font selector dropdown in spread sheet

Tags: asp.net, fonts, devexpress, spreadsheet, rich-text-editor

I want to use custom fonts same B persian fonts in my asp.net devexpress spreadsheet .
It uses just default system font in its font-selector dropdown and doesn't use my installed fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The devExpress font selector only show true-type fonts. its a .net restriction not only with devex components.